# Regex extracting string after last hyphen and spaces

Tags: regex, pcre

Which regex needs to be used to extract 'Manchester City' from string.
String is:

```
Aston Villa - Manchester City
```

I tried `-(.*)\w|-(.)`, but it grabs `-` .

Comment: which regex tool/flavor?

Comment: i test it here http://www.regextester.com/15 .I tried  -(.*)\w|-(.)  but it grabs '- '

Comment: Use a string split method, it is easier.

Comment: i cant use string split method,coz i use software that has option using regex. So its needed to extract exact string

Comment: This is basic regex. You should put some more effort in finding the sollution by educating yourself on the topic of regex; than to use up our time.

Comment: probably you are right,iam newbie to all this

Comment: Does `(?<=-\s)[^-]+$` work for you? Or even `-\s*\K[^-]+$` (if the regex flavor is PCRE). We do not know the flavor you are using. Some flavors do not support a lookbehind.

Comment: @Wiktor S  almost! The problem is that whitespace remains before string.So its needed to get rid off whitespace

Comment: Please check `(?<=-\s)[^-]+$` or even `-\s*\K[^-]+$` (if the regex flavor is PCRE)

Comment: Yep,thats correct! They work,both of them

Comment: @wiktor how can i mark that as correct answer and lift your reputation score?

Comment: Just a sec, I will write an answer.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `-(.*)\w|-(.)` matches `-` since both the alternatives here start with matching a hyphen. You can usually check if something is present or not with a lookaround.

However, in this case, I'd suggest

```
-\s*\K[^-]+$
```

Since you need to only match the substring after the last `-` with spaces trimmed off, you need something like a negative infinite width lookbehind `(?<=-\s*)`. However, in PCRE, infinite width lookbehind is not supported. Instead, there is a `\K` operator that makes the engine omit the whole match that was grabbed so far by the current pattern.

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cG4jR7/1)

Breakdown:

- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace characters
- `\K` - operator that resets (empties) all currently kept match buffer
- `[^-]+` - one or more characters other than `-` up to ...
- `$` - the end of the string.

Comment: Great!Tnx for detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is[code] . *- (. *) [/code]  and your data is in $1 or \1 or something else that depends on your tool.  That assume that data are in format xxxxx-xxxxxx

Comment: i need regex that will extract string after -. In this case Manchester City without whitspace before Man...

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option is `- (.*)` see: https://regex101.com/r/fY3oE7/1. Use the first capturing group in your language to get the part after the dash.

Comment: i tried this.But i need string without - and whitespice coz i dont use language its just software that has option of using regex

Comment: @falconProger If you retrieve the first capturing group, there is no dash or space in it